# Boost C++ libraries installation

Tags: c++, boost

I have just downloaded the boost libraries from the boost website and extracted them to my desktop. I was hoping to just have a quick look at them and have them installed on my machine and perhaps use them in the future when I am more accustomed to C++.

When I extracted it, I was confused with all of the extracted files. There is all of the headers in the boost directory but tutorials mention running bootstrap.bat (I'm using Windows).

So I am asking this: do I simply extract the headers to my compilers include directory like normal to get boost up and running or do I need to do something else?

As I understand it from searching about, apparently "most" of boost is just templates and can be used simply by including the headers, but what about the rest?

Am I totally barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you really want an understanding of what to do, follow the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/windows.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the root `boost` directory to include paths of your compiler/IDE (so if you have Boost extracted to `C:\Boost`, the compiler will use that path, not `C:\Boost\boost`).

Don't do any copying of the boost folder to your compiler's include directory, because it may make upgrading Boost harder in the future.

Also if you plan to use any of boost's compiled libraries, add Boost's `lib` directory to compiler's library search paths. Configuring the compiling step is a matter of putting the right toolset parameter to boost's build tool. If you have your command line environment configured properly, bootstrap should run and compile the builder without any problems, and the Boost builder should properly detect your toolset, so no parameters will be necessary.

As you do such configuration only once every time you do a clean install of your favorite compiler, it's not as hard or daunting as it seems.

Comment: I extracted boost to C:\boost and added this to the directory for include paths of CodeBlocks and attempted to compile the test program (near the top of the page) from: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html only to get a fatal error when attempting to compile saying no such file or directory. Can't see what I have done wrong here?

Comment: #include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
I checked to make sure it was in there just in case and surely enough it was in a subdirectory "lambda"

Comment: Nevermind, I just remembered I had the same sort of problem when I tried including SDL headers from elsewhere other than in my MinGW directory so I extracted boost into a folder of its own into MinGW and recompiled, worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you run Windows, take a look at this automated installer:
► http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Also, some general advice:

> do I simply extract the headers to my compilers include directory

No! Do not pollute your compiler's includes with third-party includes; make a separate directory specifically for a particular library. You'll then need to tell your specific IDE in what directory it can find the library headers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using CodeBlocks and these appear to be for Microsoft Visual C++ though. Not sure it that makes any difference or not.

Comment: @Michael : It does make a difference -- the libraries built with VC++ are not usable with GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [boostpro's](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) installer, it is less work.  I vaguely remember having to set up the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable on one of my systems to use it.

The libraries that contained compiled source should be included in the installer.

If you don't use the installer (or don't set up your build correctly), and try to use the libraries that need it you will likely get some linker errors when you try and compile your program.  Usually if you take those linker errors and plop them in google it tells you pretty quick which libraries you need to include in your build system.  I use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) for that and have been very happy..